# Make object to follow hair particles (bend)

Tags: hair

If I make simple hair setup and make object as render object it doesn't bend. How to make objects to follow the curve?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UOXS7TlKizlf98XeIVA_RmuyTtYhXNpf/view?usp=share_link

[image]

Comment: did u subdivide your object? if yes, please provide blend file because you didn't show us any settings you made. thx.

Comment: You should add more information of you hair, is it particle system or hair curves, what setting do you have (you should describe all or add screenshot to get a better answer. Instead of just adding the blend file

Comment: Hi. Please don't post essential information like links, file downloads or additional details in the comments section where it can be easily missed. Instead edit them into your original post with the [Edit] button above. Comments are transitory by nature, are hard to index or search for, and may be erased at any moment.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of *Render As `Object`* try the *Particle Instance* modifier.

1. switch *Render As* to `None` in the *Particle System Properties*.
2. edit the particle instance object and move the mesh to the *World Origin (0, 0, 0)*. Rotate it so that it is aligned along the Y-axis in positive direction.
   [image: particle instance]
3. apply the *Scale* and *Location* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> in *Object* mode) so the scale is set to (1, 1, 1) and the origin (orange dot) is at (0, 0, 0)
4. add a *Particle Instance* modifier to the particle instance (*Plane* object) and adjust the settings.
   [image: particle instance modifier]